# How to declare a state variable as a Type on Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typeof

I have the type:

```
export type AVAILABLE_API_STATUS =
  | "Created"
  | "Process"
  | "Analisis"
  | "Refused";
```

I would like to know how to create a state with the type above.

I tried to:

```
const [state] = React.useState<AVAILABLE_API_STATUS>("Refused");
```

But it asks for me to use typeof before the Type:

```
const [status] = React.useState<typeof AVAILABLE_API_STATUS>("Refused");
```

But it does not accept the 'Refused' value;

[image: desc]

Comment: How **exactly** is `AVAILABLE_API_STATUS` defined? You stated it's `export type`, but it clearly is not the case.

Comment: What do you mean, @zerkms? My intention is to use as interfaces are consumed. Is it possible?

Comment: The error message states it's a **value**, while you claim you declared it as a type.

Comment: You have a `|` character before `"Created"`. Try removing that.

Comment: @Isuru it's okay to have it

Comment: @zerkms thanks I learnt something today. :)

Comment: Hello, people. First of all, thanks for trying to help me. Zerk, I want to declare this state as the value "Refused", which on Type AVAILABLE_API_STATUS is an option to be..

Answer (score 2):

In the error message it says `AVAILABLE_API_STATUS` instead of the `AVAILABLE_API` you defined above. Is it possible you have a `const AVAILABLE_API_STATUS` and the `type AVAILABLE_API` and you mixed them up in the code?
Because this works for me:

```js
export type AVAILABLE_API =
  | 'Created'
  | 'Process'
  | 'Analisis'
  | 'Refused';

export const TestComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<AVAILABLE_API>('Refused');
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => setState('Refused')}
    >
      {state}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hello, Opsi. Firstly, thank you. I already edit the labels above